# (FRAGMENT) UPDATE LISTVIEW WHEN I CLICK FRAGMENT MENU

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

if i delete item/s on listview and then i click the home menu in  navigation drawer the listview won't update.

## here's my mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navLogout;
String[] navMenuTitles;
TypedArray navMenuIcons;

ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.nav_drawer_items_not_login);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // login
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // register
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // classic brownies
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // cupcakes
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // cookies
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // feedback
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // about
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(5, -1)));

    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                // accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                // accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);

    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item

        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    Fragment fragment = null;

    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        Toast.makeText(this, "search selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;

    case R.id.action_shoppingcart:

        Toast.makeText(this, "shopping cart selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

        fragment = new FeedbackFragment();

        return true;

    default:
        break;

    }
    return true;
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_shoppingcart).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        fragment = new HomeFragment();

        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new LoginFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new RegisterFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new ClassicBrowniesFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new CupcakesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new CookiesFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new FeedbackFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new AboutFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

## here's my HomeFragment

_just asking question, using some more words to describe your problem will always help. If there are really nothing more to say.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {


String[] member_names;
TypedArray product_icons;
String[] statues;
String[] contactType;

List<RowItem> rowItems;
ListView mylistview;
CustomAdapter myadapter;
CustomAdapter newadapter;

public HomeFragment() {
}

View rootView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
            false);


    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    member_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Member_names);

    product_icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.product_icons);

    statues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.statues);

    for (int i = 0; i < member_names.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(member_names[i],
                product_icons.getResourceId(i, -1), statues[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    mylistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
    product_icons.recycle();
    mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    mylistview.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

    mylistview.invalidateViews();
    return rootView;



}

public void updateList(ArrayAdapter adapter){
    mylistview = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
}



@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    String member_name = rowItems.get(position).getMember_name();
    int product_icons = rowItems.get(position).getProfile_pic_id();
    String status = rowItems.get(position).getStatus();

    RowItem item = rowItems.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            FeedbackFragment.class);
    intent.putExtra(member_name, item.getMember_name());

    intent.putExtra(status, item.getStatus());

    rowItems.remove(item);
    newadapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    mylistview.setAdapter(newadapter);
    newadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            "Added to Cart: " + member_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a logical issue here. You are removing the item and updating the listView, which is correct, but you are not changing the actual List `List<RowItem> rowItems;` beyond the current scope. When you select HomeFragment again, you are creating a new instance and everything resets.

One solution might be to pass the data from the updated `List<RowItem> rowItems;` to the next Fragment so that the changes you made are reflected in other Fragments.

Currently, you create your `List<RowItem> rowItems` by piecing together the following:

```
member_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Member_names);

product_icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.product_icons);

statues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.statues);
```

However, when you remove the `RowItem` from the list, you don't change any of those three variables. Thus, when the new instance of the Fragment is initialized, you create a brand new List of `RowItems` using the same old data.

In short, here are two possible solutions:

1. Update the variables `member_names`, `product_icons`, `statues` when you remove the item from the list
2. Pass the List of `RowItem` between the Fragments

Comment: if i delete one of the listview's item and then i start clicking the home button in the fragment, the listview is not updated, the items i deleted start to appear again  ;/

Comment: Right. Because you are creating a new `List<RowItem> rowItems` each time you start a new HomeFragment. You add to this list by piecing together three variables. However, when you remove the item from the `List`, you don't change the variables that you started with to create that `List`.